# Converting volume (gallons) to mass (grams) using jscience?

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jscience

I can't seem to find/remember a specific formula to convert units of volume to units of mass. I think it has to do with density, but how would this be done?

In my case, I'm trying to write a program using the [JScience library](http://jscience.org/api/overview-summary.html) to convert any type of unit the user might input into the standard `SI.GRAM` unit.

The problem comes in with trying to describe things like honey, which are commonly measure in gallons, grams, pounds, and ounces.

I have the following code mostly working when working with units of mass, but I get a `ConversionException` when trying to work with gallons, which is understandable, since it's measuring volume and not mass.

```
javax.measure.converter.ConversionException: gal is not compatible with g
```

Here's what I've got so far. Also, I chose to break up the `Amount<Mass>` into `amount_value` and `amount_unit` because I want to store this in an SQLite database and also have it be represented as text, so I am storing it like this for serialization purposes.

```
public class Sugar {

    private String type;
    private double amount_value;
    private String amount_unit;


    public Sugar(SUGAR_TYPES type, Amount<Mass> amount) {
        this.type = type.toString();
        this.amount_value = amount.getEstimatedValue();
        this.amount_unit = amount.getUnit().toString();
    }    

    public Amount<Mass> getAmount() {
        BaseUnit<Mass> mass_unit = new BaseUnit<>(amount_unit);
        return Amount.valueOf(amount_value, mass_unit);     
    }

    public SUGAR_TYPES getType() {
         return (type != null) ? SUGAR_TYPES.valueOf(type) : null;
    }

    public double getAmountInGrams() {
        Amount<Mass> mass_unit = getAmount();
        switch (mass_unit.getUnit().toString().toLowerCase()) {
            case "g":
                return mass_unit.getEstimatedValue();
            case "gal":
                // this throws the ConversionException
                return NonSI.GALLON_LIQUID_US.getConverterTo(SI.GRAM).convert(mass_unit.getEstimatedValue());
            case "lb":
                return NonSI.POUND.getConverterTo(SI.GRAM).convert(mass_unit.getEstimatedValue());
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, String.format("Failed to get Amount<Mass> in SI.GRAM for amount %s and unit %s.",
                        amount_value, amount_unit));
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(mass_unit.getUnit().toString());
        }
    }

    public enum SUGAR_TYPES {
        HONEY, SUCROSE, APPLES, APRICOTS, APRICOTS_DRIED, BANANAS, BLACKBERRY, BLUEBERRY,
        BOYSENBERRY, CANTALOUPE, CELERY, CHERRY_DARK_SWEET, CRANBERRY, CURRANT_BLACK, DATES, 
        DATES_DRIED, DEWBERRY, ELDERBERRY, FIGS, FIGS_DRIED, GOOSEBERRY, GRAPE_CONCORD,
        GRAPES, GRAPEFRUIT, GUANABANA, GUAVAS, HONEYDEW_MELON, JACKFRUIT, KIWIS, LEMON_JUICE,
        LITCHI, LOGANBERRY, MANGOS, MAPLE_SYRUP, PLUMS, RAISINS_DRIED, RASPBERRY_BLACK,
        RASPBERRY_RED, RHUBARB, STRAWBERRY, TANGERINES, WATERMELONS
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I have other classes that need to have a similar way of converting a generic unit into the SI unit.

Comment: `density = mass / volume`. If you can't remember that, think of the unit: `kg/m^3` - literally, mass over volume.

Comment: Right, but is there a nice/standard way to do this with common items like honey and fruit juice, besides having a lookup table of densities and doing the conversion myself?

Comment: The definition of volume and mass _requires_ that you know the density of the _particular material._  If you want to avoid a lookup table, you will need to live in a different reality.

Comment: Well, 1 cm^3 of water is 1 gram.

Comment: Well thanks guys, really can't believe I forgot the formula for volume, and I guess I just have to make that density lookup table to do this right.

Answer (score 0):

You will need mass per volume values for everything you want to calculate. For example, you could expand your enum to include a gram per litre (or kg per m^3, whatever works best for you). You cannot just convert volume to weight without this information:

Example: 1 litre of water=1kg, but 1 litre of petrol=0.88 kg.

Then you only need to convert input volume to your default volume, look up the type, multiply the converted volume with your saved gram per litre and return the result.